# ffmpeg Inserting Extra Frame when Transcoding a Stack of Images Using H.264

Tags: python, ffmpeg

So I have a stack of images named `1.jpeg`, `2.jpeg`, and so on.

I've been using the following command in Python successfully to create a `.mp4` from these images:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -f image2 -i %d.jpeg -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -r " + str(FrameRate) + " " + OutputDirectory + "\\" + OutputName + ".mp4")
```

The problem I'm encountering right now is that when I do this I am able to successfully create a video but the video is about twice as long as it should be. I can't seem to figure out why ffmpeg would be inserting extra frames into my video. Any guidance in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of `FrameRate`?

Comment: Well, did you get the framerate right? Maybe multiply it by 2?

Comment: I checked and I got the framerate right. For the record it's 40 and I checked and made sure it is in fact 40.

Comment: You need to remove that and insert `-framerate 40` **before**  `-i $d.jpeg`

Comment: so if I rearranged the command and put framerate first you think it would solve the extra frame issue? Any info on why that would cause a problem though?

Comment: Without using the `-framerate` input option the default rate of 25 will be applied. So by adding the `-r 40` output option it had to convert from 25 to 40 by duplicating frames.

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate the help with this. Everything works.